# Is there any way that we can self-host openmaptiles server running HTTPs (to serve vector tiles)

Tags: openmaptiles

I was following https://openmaptiles.com/server/ guide to self-host a vector tiles server by using Docker (Kitematic), it was working well but i couldn't find the way to configure to run the server on HTTPs (since my application is running on HTTPs and it's not allowed to request to get tiles from HTTP server)

Please help to advise on this matter?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use some front-end server for this, for example, Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a front-end server such as the nginx or apache for doing proxy from https to http - and be sure to set `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

Or setup CloudFlare.com account for your domain and get HTTPS and global CDN acting as a proxy.

Comment: Hello! I'm using Nginx and while the `X-Forwarded-Proto` does set the protocol to https in my map style, adding the `X-Forwarded-Host` header doesn't seem to do anything.
This is my Nginx reverse proxy setup:
`location / {
      rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;

   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host mapserver.animus.host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
   }`
And when I `curl https://mapserver.animus.host/styles/klokantech-basic/style.json`, the urls contain `https://localhost:8080/...`.

Edit: sorry for the bad formatting